# Angular Material icons styling

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, styles

I am trying to align the controls in a line. I've tried different paddings/margins. How can I do this?

[image]

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px">
    <button (click)="goToPage(1)" [disabled]="pageNumber==1">
        <md-icon>first_page</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button (click)="previous()" [disabled]="pageNumber==1">
        <md-icon>chevron_left</md-icon>
    </button>
    <input #input type="text" style="width: 30px;height:30px;margin-top:2px" (keyup.enter)="goToPage(input.value)" [(value)]="pageNumber" >

    <button (click)="next()" [disabled]="pageNumber==totalPages">
        <md-icon>chevron_right</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button (click)="goToPage(totalPages)" [disabled]="pageNumber==totalPages">
        <md-icon>last_page</md-icon>
    </button>
    <br />

    <span>Showing page {{pageNumber}} of {{totalPages}} pages.
    </span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

The first one is that your buttons are missing the angular material styling and the second one is that you should learn CSS before jumping to any JavaScript frameworks like Angular. Anyway I made a [working demo on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z8FL0N4Cc59xHpSjpnhZ?p=preview) for you.

[image]

I just added a few CSS selectors and I used flexbox just like this:

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
  .wrapper button, input {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
  }
```